# Three js renderer size issues. Trying to set a perfect size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on three js model , to embed the model to my website. Finally made it but there's only one problem.I couldn't get the renderer.setSize() to fit my div. In other words, I can see scroll bar which I don't want to see there. How do I setSize so that it perfectly fits my canvas ?

I saw one post regarding the same problem , he wanted to avoid scrolling as well. I tried to follow the answer as stated in the post but nothing's going on. Then I headed to three js documentation , followed what stated there.

```
.setSize ( width : Integer, height : Integer, updateStyle : Boolean ) : null
```

Still couldn't figure it out. Why even the code in documentation is not working ? BUT , i'm not sure if I found a trick , I was just playing around with the setSize values.

```
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth * 0.99 ,window.innerHeight * 0.99);
```

as you can see there , I added * 0.99 , and there's no more scroll bar! Didn't mean to do it this way , but what's the correct code to adjust it ? Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>THEE JS BOX APP</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100% }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OBJloader.js"></script>
        <script>

            // CREATING AN EMPTY SCENE
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // CAMERA
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 9000 );
            camera.position.z = 200;

            // ORBIT CONTROL
            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

            // RENDERER
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor("#ffffff");
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth * 0.99 ,window.innerHeight * 0.99);
            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;


            // APPEND RENDERER TO DOM
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            // WINDOW RESIZE
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            function onWindowResize(){
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }

            // instantiate a loader
            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

            // load a resource
            loader.load(
                // resource URL
                'img/logovoivode1.obj',
                // called when resource is loaded
                function ( object ) {
                    scene.add( object );
                },
                // called when loading is in progresses
                function ( xhr ) {
                    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
                },
                // called when loading has errors
                function ( error ) {
                    console.log( 'An error happened' );
                }
            );

            // ***************************** LIGHTING **********************************//

            // White directional light at half intensity shining from the top.
            //var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 5 );
            //scene.add( directionalLight );

            var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.5); // soft white light
            scene.add( light );

            var pointlight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.5, 1000);
            light.position.set(10, 0, 25);
            scene.add(pointlight);

            //var DLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 50);
            //scene.add(DLight);

            // var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 0.5, 1000, 0.3);

            // ************************ END-OF-LIGHTING *****************************//

            // CREATING A BOX
            // var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
            // var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, wireframe:true});
            // var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);


            // ADD CUBE TO THE SCENE
            // scene.add(cube);
            // ANIMATION LOOP

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                //scene.rotation.x += 0.01;
                //scene.rotation.y += 0.01;
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also try setting the margin on html to 0

Comment: already set to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by "inner element whitespaces".

When an html parser parses your source code, it also parses the spaces/entets/tabs between your tags as text, and then makes it smaller till its just 1 space. This 1 space is the cause of your issue, but knowing what causes it is the first step to solving the problem.

> Original problem, for reference:
>
> ```css
> body {
>     margin: 0;
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 100%;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
> <script>
>     // CREATING AN EMPTY SCENE
>     var scene = new THREE.Scene();
>
>     // CAMERA
>     var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 9000 );
>     camera.position.z = 200;
>
>     // ORBIT CONTROL
>     var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
>
>     // RENDERER
>     var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
>     renderer.setClearColor("#ffffff");
>     renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth  ,window.innerHeight);
>     renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
>     renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
>
>     // APPEND RENDERER TO DOM
>     document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
>
>     // WINDOW RESIZE
>     window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
>
>     function onWindowResize(){
>         camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
>         camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
>         renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
>     }
>
>     scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,130,70), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x444444 }) ) );
>
>     function animate() {
>         requestAnimationFrame( animate );
>         renderer.render( scene, camera );
>     }
>     animate();
> </script>
> ```

### Using `font-size: 0`

By setting the `font-size` to 0, you basically squash the space to PX width and height, making sure it doesn't contribute to your problem

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
    // CREATING AN EMPTY SCENE
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // CAMERA
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 9000 );
    camera.position.z = 200;

    // ORBIT CONTROL
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

    // RENDERER
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor("#ffffff");
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth  ,window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

    // APPEND RENDERER TO DOM
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // WINDOW RESIZE
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    function onWindowResize(){
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    }

    scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,130,70), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x444444 }) ) );

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    animate();
</script>
```

### Using `overflow: hidden`

Just take our problems, and hide them for the next person trying to fix it properly.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
    // CREATING AN EMPTY SCENE
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // CAMERA
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 9000 );
    camera.position.z = 200;

    // ORBIT CONTROL
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

    // RENDERER
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor("#ffffff");
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth  ,window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

    // APPEND RENDERER TO DOM
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // WINDOW RESIZE
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    function onWindowResize(){
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    }

    scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,130,70), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x444444 }) ) );

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    animate();
</script>
```

### Using `display: flex`

When you use the flex display mode, the browser ignores all inner white spaces in the current element

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
    // CREATING AN EMPTY SCENE
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // CAMERA
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 9000 );
    camera.position.z = 200;

    // ORBIT CONTROL
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

    // RENDERER
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor("#ffffff");
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth  ,window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

    // APPEND RENDERER TO DOM
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // WINDOW RESIZE
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    function onWindowResize(){
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    }

    scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,130,70), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x444444 }) ) );

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    animate();
</script>
```

### Setting the display of the canvas to block

If you set the display property of the canvas to `block`, then you don't have to worry about the inner element white spaces, as they don't have anny effect between block elements.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
    // CREATING AN EMPTY SCENE
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // CAMERA
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 9000 );
    camera.position.z = 200;

    // ORBIT CONTROL
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

    // RENDERER
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor("#ffffff");
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth  ,window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

    // APPEND RENDERER TO DOM
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // WINDOW RESIZE
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    function onWindowResize(){
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    }

    scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,130,70), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x444444 }) ) );

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    animate();
</script>
```